# Subtracting a mat from scalar value

Tags: android, opencv, alphablending

Im trying to do alpha blending as in [learnopencv](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/AlphaBlending/alphaBlend.py)

```
  //Load the bitmap
            foregroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.dominant);
            backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.call);
            alphaBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.trans);

        //initalize mat objects
        foreground = new Mat();
        background = new Mat();
        alpha = new Mat();

        //Convert bitmap to mat
        Utils.bitmapToMat(foregroundBitmap, foreground);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(backgroundBitmap, background);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(alphaBitmap, alpha);

        // Convert Mat to float data type
        foreground.convertTo(foreground, CV_32FC3);
        background.convertTo(background, CV_32FC3);

        // Normalize the alpha mask to keep intensity between 0 and 1
        alpha.convertTo(alpha, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255);

       // Storage for output image
        Mat ouImage = Mat.zeros(foreground.size(), foreground.type());


        // Multiply the foreground with the alpha matte
        multiply(alpha, foreground, foreground);

        multiply(1.0-alpha, background, background);


        add(foreground, background, ouImage);
```

but it is throwing the following error

> Error:(62, 21) error: bad operand types for binary operator '-' first
>   type:  double second type: Mat

This points to `multiply(1.0-alpha, background, background);`

How do i subtract a mat from scalar value?

Comment: try with `multiply(new Scalar(1.0-alpha), background, background);`

Comment: still the same error :(

Comment: is  it possible to fill a matrix with all ones

Comment: the number of elements in `Scalar` must match the number of channels in background Mat.

Comment: can u please elaborate on how do I match them?

Comment: will it work if i create a matrix with ones and subtract it with alpha?

Comment: can i use  Core.subtract to subtract mat from scalar?

Comment: Yes you can subtract a `Scalar` from `Mat`, but cannot do the reverse. Suppose you have a `Mat` with 3 channels, then you need to fabricate the `Scalar` as `Scalar(10, 10, 10)`, or `Scalar(10)` if your `Mat` is single channel.

Comment: ok thanks.. what is an alternative for  cv2.multiply(1.0 - alpha, background)